# FCM Token with colon (:) returns Bad Request in Azure NH

Tags: push-notification, azure-notificationhub

We are currently trying to implement Azure Notification Hub with Firebase Cloud Messaging and are hitting a bit of a stumbling block.

When we pass the FCM token to any method, we receive a 400 Bad Request, and it's due to the format of the FCM token containing the colon (':').

For example, if I pass "ABCDE:12387231821" to this method, it will break:

```
private async Task<bool> CheckTokenExistence(string fcmToken)
    {
        var client = 
            NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
            ListenConnectionString,
            NotificationHub,
            enableTestSend: true);

            Debug.WriteLine($"checking FCM token existence...");

            return await client.RegistrationExistsAsync(fcmToken);
    }
```

**Edit: Included stack info**

The path 'sb://notification-hub-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/push-notification/Registrations/**FCM:KeyHere**/?api-version=2017-04' contains character(s) that are not allowed by Service Bus. Entity segments can contain only letters, numbers, periods (.), hyphens (-), and underscores (_)

Comment: Found partial issue - the RegistrationExistsAsync method does **not** take the FCM token, but some other registration token.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?